# Pull CME price data into Python 3.6.8

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib3

I am relatively new to Python so I apologize if this is a 'bush league' question.

I am trying to retrieve the WTI futures prices from this website:
https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_quotes_globex.html

Which libraries should I be using?  How will I need to adjust the output when it is pulled from the website?

Currently operating in Python 3.6.8 with the pandas, numpy, requests, urllib3, BeautifulSoup, and json libraries. I am not exactly sure if these are the correct libraries and if they are which functions I should be using.

Here is a basic version of the code:

```
wtiFutC = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_quotes_globex.html'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response2 = http.request('GET', wtiFutC)
print(type(response2.data)) #check the type of the data produced - bytes
print(response2.data) #prints out the data

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.data.decode('utf-8'), features='html.parser')
print(type(soup2)) #check the type of the data produced - 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'
print(soup2) #prints out the BeautifulSoup version of the data
```

I want a way to see the 'Last' price for the WTI future for the whole curve.  Instead I am seeing something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<!--[if (gt IE 9) |!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="cmePineapple no-js" lang="en" xml:lang="en" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I see no values at present. Are you after the entire last price column?

Comment: @QHarr - that is correct. I was looking for the entire last price column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the endpoint the page does and parse out the column of interest (and date) from the json

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Quotes/Future/4707/G?quoteCodes=null&_=1560171518204').json()
last_quotes = [(item['expirationDate'], item['last']) for item in r['quotes']]
```

Comment: I realized that I made a mistake with the original link that I posted (my apologies) - the link should have been:  https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_quotes_globex.html  - how did you get the link in that json style?

Comment: I used the network tab in dev tools to find the endpoint the page was using to update content. That returns json.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you on this.  In my Google Chrome browser, I have the dev tools screen up and I selected the network tab. At this point I'm pretty lost regarding how I find the "endpoint" that the page was using to update content.  Any additional direction you could provide?

Comment: click refresh to load all the network activity then click any url in the network tab and press Ctrl + F - in the search box that appears enter any value from the page that you would expect to be retrieved. You should then get a list of all matches in network traffic.

Comment: that was perfect!  Thank you again for your direction!  Super helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

The data in that webpage is javascript generated, making it hard to extract data with packages like `requests`. 
 If it's not a big of a deal I suggest you look for a different source of data that uses minimal or no javascript. Then using `requests` to get the webpage source and extract data from it.

You extract the data using libraries like `BeautifulSoup` or `re`(or even `pandas` in some cases), and feed them to libraries like `numpy` or `pandas` if you want to analyze and do calculations on the data.

Otherwise i suggest you take a look at `Selenium` for javascript support.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/). It’s a great resource if you’re already familiar with requests.